# Creality v1.1.5 board replacement UP1 Chip

Tags: creality-ender-3

While I was having fun with my ender I burn out **UP1 Chip**.

Does anyone know **which chip is that** (I can't see because of burnt) and **where can I order it**?

Image: [Damaged chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVuxP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an **MP1584** chip. 
Guys on Reddit helped me out.

[link](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32958513528.html?spm=2114.search0301.3.14.220749f5Wpx4xL&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=a486b56c-998e-48c6-bcf3-3800d4adfaee&algo_expid=a486b56c-998e-48c6-bcf3-3800d4adfaee-2)